# Auditing the logged in user

Tags: .net, wcf

I have 2 boxes say Machine1 and Machine2. Both are in a same domain (ABC_Domain) network. A .net web application (DotNet_Web_App) and a WCF (WCF_Service) are hosted in Machine1 and Machine2 respectively. Both DotNet_Web_App and WCF_Service are hosted thru IIS. And the app pools on which IIS are configured to run on same domain account (ABC_Domain\ServiceAccount). Now a user (ABC_Domain\User1) is accessing the web application DotNet_Web_App that interacts with WCF_Service for some sort of operations.

Is it possible to capture in WCF_Service the actual user trying to access it thru the web application? In this given above scenario, can I find the ABC_Domain\User1 in WCF_Service? This is to audit the actual users in WCF_Service those who are trying to access it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check `System.ServiceModel.ServiceSecurityContext.Current.PrimaryIdentity`,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicesecuritycontext.aspx

http://davesquared.net/2008/04/getting-current-identity-in-wcf.html